# Minimizing Huber Loss

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, least-absolute-deviations, huber

Huber Loss is given as follows:

[image]

I'd like to proof $\gamma=median\{y_1,...y_N \}$ minimizes the Huber Loss so i've taken its first derivate for $\gamma\neq y_i$:

[image]

I've tried to proof that first derivate change its signal before and after the median, i mean $\frac{\partial R}{\partial \gamma}<0$ when $\lambda< median$ and $\frac{\partial R}{\partial \gamma}>0$ when $\lambda > median$ but i didnt get any satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the definition of Huber loss: $\delta$ should be before the parentheses in the second addend.
$$
R = \sum_{|y_i-\gamma| \leq \delta} \frac{1}{2}\left(y_i - \gamma\right)^2 + \sum_{|y_i-\gamma| > \delta} \delta \left(|y_i - \gamma| - \frac{\delta}{2}\right)
$$

But ultimately, there is a bigger problem here: unless I'm misunderstanding something, you cannot prove your theorem, because it's not true.

Consider $y = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 10\}$ and $\delta = 6$. For $\gamma = median(y) = 3$, the Huber loss is $R = 42$. However, for $\gamma = 4$, the Huber loss is $R = 25$, which shows that $median(y)$ does not minimise the Huber loss.